# Example of the real numbers $x$ appearing in the Jarnik's theorem: $||nx||\leq n^{-\beta}$ for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for fixed $\beta>1$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, real-numbers, fractions, diophantine-approximation

According to Falconer (Falconer, '85, *The Geometry of Fractal Sets*, theorem 8.16, p. 134), a part of the Jarnik's theorem is the following:

> Take $\beta>1$. The set of real numbers $x$ for which the intequality $||nx||\leq n^{-\beta}$ holds for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{N}$ has Hausdorff dimension $2/(1 + \beta)$.

where $||.||$ is the distance to the nearest integer in regular Euclidean norm.

Falconer doesn't provide an example of such a real number $x$ so I got curious about knowing some examples of $x$s, besides the obvious candidate $x = 0$. Do you know some or do you know a good source for this?

Comment: $\Vert x \Vert$ is *not* the Euclidean norm in this context, but the distance of $x$ to the nearest integer (defined on page 131).

Comment: @MartinR That makes more sense. I'll edit the post. In any case, my question remains the same.

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but apparently every rational number $x$ satisfies that condition.

Comment: @MartinR Interesting! Do you happen to know a proof/a reference?

Comment: If $x=p/q$ is rational then $ nx$ is an integer for all $n$ which are a multiple of $q$, so that $\Vert nx \Vert = 0 \le n^{-\beta}$ holds for infinitely many $n$.